# Get the first character of a string, to get initial from name

Tags: vb.net

I have to shorten the length of a string variable to one character. The problem arises as I don't know the length of the variable.

The code I have written has been designed to take a first name and surname and display them in a label in the format of **SURNAME.INITIAL**.

How would I be able to shorten the length of the variable FirstName to one letter?

Comment: `Dim Initial As String = FirstName.Substring(0, 1)` If necessary, check first to see if FirstName is empty.

Comment: Thank you @Blackwood - The code now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have the string **Mary**. To get the **M** you can do this:

```
Dim str As String
str = "Mary"

Dim first_char As Char
first_char = str.Substring(0, 1)
```

**first_char** will have the **M**

Comment: Actually it will produce a runtime error because you have a space between `str` and `.Substring`.

Comment: @Jeroen __Visual Basic__ will automatically remove the space between them. It would run Successfully. As you build the project, it will automatically be changed into `str.Substring(0, 1)`

Comment: Or you could just take the space out of your code example... Either way, this code will NOT compile if you have `Option Strict` on (and you should) because of the implicit conversion between `Char` and `String`...

Comment: Besides, it's not Visual Basic that will remove the space, it's the Visual Studio IDE. The OP could very well be coding in another environment. People do use Mono, you know?

Comment: You both know this discussion is out of topic right?

Comment: No it isn't off topic, we are discussing a mistake in your answer... :-)